# Errors related to Android NDK

Tags: android, video, android-ndk

Running [this](https://github.com/frankandrobot/FFvideoLiveWallpaper) in my android device gives me these errors.

```
    Exception Ljava/lang/UnsatisfiedLinkError; thrown while initializing Lffvideolivewallpaper/frankandrobot/com/NativeCalls;
    Shutting down VM
    threadid=1: thread exiting with uncaught exception (group=0x40ed42a0)
    FATAL EXCEPTION: main
    java.lang.ExceptionInInitializerError
    at ffvideolivewallpaper.frankandrobot.com.VideoLiveWallpaper.onSharedPreferenceChanged(VideoLiveWallpaper.java:144)
    at ffvideolivewallpaper.frankandrobot.com.VideoLiveWallpaper.onCreate(VideoLiveWallpaper.java:78)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.handleCreateService(ActivityThread.java:2404)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.access$1600(ActivityThread.java:140)
    at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1309)
    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4898)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1006)
    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:773)
    at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
    Caused by: java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError: Couldn't load avcore: findLibrary returned null
    at java.lang.Runtime.loadLibrary(Runtime.java:365)
    at java.lang.System.loadLibrary(System.java:535)
    at ffvideolivewallpaper.frankandrobot.com.NativeCalls.(NativeCalls.java:42)
    ... 13 more
```

I think these errors are related to Android NDK. Can anyone guide me on this, keeping in mind that I have no prior knowledge of Android NDK and how it works.

Comment: As the error states, locate the 'libavcore.so' file on your device. That being missing is the root cause of this error.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the reason why I was getting this error, because I did not build the native libraries. I used ndk-build and the errors got resolved.

Answer (score 0):

This may happen if we install the app on a device where the previous version was already installed we always get this kind of error:

Just look at this similar problem : https://groups.google.com/d/topic/android-ndk/YmKly4zEMQ0/discussion

Comment: I reinstalled the app after deleting it. I'm still facing the same problem.